# VSTS dotnet Nuget Pack: Is not a valid version string

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create a prerelease build for a .net-standard 2.0 library in VSTS. I have created a build with the following steps

1. dotnet restore version 2
2. dotnet build version 2
3. dotnet pack version 2
4. nuget push version 2

When I use the environment variable (PackageName) as `$(Build.BuildNumber)-beta` as my pack version. The pack fails with the error `BuildName_2018.7.11.1-beta is not a valid version string`. I have previously used this environment variable as my pack version in .net-framework builds with success.

Answer (score 5):

The version does not meet Nuget Package Version format. It must start with numbers like following:

> 1.0.1
>
> 6.11.1231
>
> 4.3.1-rc
>
> 2.2.44-beta1

So you need to remove the strings in your build number format. Refer to this link for details: [Package versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning).

Comment: My own problem was that my version started with `v0.1.0`  the `v` was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to go to only 3 sets of numbers instead of 4. So instead of `2018.7.11.1-beta` try `2018.7.11-beta1`. I believe 4 sets of numbers will work for the .net dll itself, but not for nuget.

REF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning

Answer (score 1):

That's because the string `$(Build.BuildNumber)-beta` is not an environment variable.

You can try to create a variable e.g `$(packversion)` and set the string `$(Build.BuildNumber)-beta` as the value of that variable, then use the environment variable  `$(packversion)` in `dotnet pack` task.

---

**UPDATE:**

Seems it can only identify the string which end with number as the version string.

So, just try adding the "**beta**" as prefix like this `Beta-$(Build.BuildNumber)`, then check if that works.

[image]

Comment: my variable is set up like that and it still errors out

Comment: @JoeJazdzewski What about removing the string "`-beta`"? just use the variable `$(Build.BuildNumber)`

Comment: when "-beta" is removed it works but I am trying to make a prerelease build. I have also tried other words besides "-beta" and I get the same thing

Comment: @JoeJazdzewski Just try adding the "`beta`" as prefix like this `Beta-$(Build.BuildNumber)`, then check if that works.

Comment: @JoeJazdzewski Any update? Is the string `Beta-$(Build.BuildNumber)` working for you?

Comment: That broke the build too `beta-GuidantFinancial.ServiceBusMessages Dev_2018.7.24.1' is not a valid version string` when I used `beta-$Build.BuildNumber` as my variable value

Comment: @JoeJazdzewski Please note that the `space` cannot be included in the sting, also you can have a try with set variable e.g.: $(packversion) and 
 `Beta-$(Build.BuildNumber)` as the value. Make sure no space there..

Comment: I am now getting that `BuildName_2018.7.25 is not a valid version string`. It looks like that the '_' is not a valid character for `dotnet pack`

Comment: @JoeJazdzewski So, just try  to replace the   ' `_ `'  with ' `. `', then check it again.

Comment: @JoeJazdzewski Have you resolved the issue? any update?